# Webservices to image hosting on S3?

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I use Amazon S3 to store images used in my other Java applications. Recently I had to update my apps to introduce functionality like categories, tags and so on. For now this was resolved as JSON configs stored in S3. Those are fetched by other applications and used as some kind of DB replacement :).

Other improvements like ratings and user feedbacks are still to be done. So moving to DB + backend with some webservices is next logical step. In first place I haven't used something like EC2 instance because of additional costs and maintenance issues.

I need some recommendations how to implement this with min time and effort. So basic requirements are: - image are stored on s3 - web service provides methods to fetch category list, list of links to s3 for images in category, methods to update some image ratings, and possibly in future a method to resize image to provided dimentions.

My thoughts are: - Use s3 as its already there. - add some Java hosting to run mentioned webservice (I don't like the idea of using EC2 as requires much more time for configuration that I'm willing to spend, maybe I'm wrong here). - use "plain" javaee or some light frameworks to get most of hardware.

I also considered using some image hosting service, but I haven't found something simmilar. Or maybe there is some opensource solutions that can be used for image hosting.

Any thoughts on this would be highly appreciated, cause this is just driving me nuts when trying to decide how this should be implemented.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks to me that you are looking like Document Management Sytem. I have used this before.. which has inbuilt api's to fetch the data and search on documents and open source as well.
http://www.alfresco.com/

Comment: Yeah, I thought about alfresco, but I guess that would be an overkill for me. Too heavy to just store images with ratings and tags.

Comment: Is there any "image-tagging" wrapper for Solr?

Comment: From Solr 1.4 there is an image-tagging feature, I found some information googling around.

Comment: I've googled too, but I still I have no idea how to configure all that.. (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think S3 and JSON can continue to work well for you without the trouble of going to a full relational database system.

If you imagine your solution in relational form, you can translate it into an S3 representation by mapping tables to directories in S3, rows to individual files in S3 and column values within each row as a JSON structure stored in that file. Storing small amounts of data in each "row" = S3 file allows you to update the data easily. As transfers to S3 either succeed or fail entirely, your updates will remain consistent.

To discover how many rows you have in a table, you would use the S3 list capability to list files with the common prefix for that table.

The S3 console enables you to see and explore your file structures.

Security can be provided by Amazon IAM.

Automated backup can be done by using lifecycle rules to copy to Amazon Glacier.

If you use this approach you get a lot of relational like capabilities but without the additional expense and complexity of running an EC2 server or of using Amazon RDS.

Finally, programming all this is simple, as you have the tools in place already from your previous work. I suspect that you will have a package like this to perform all the necessary operations on S3:

```
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------     
    // Amazon S3
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------     
        class S3 extends AmazonS3Client
         {final String bucket;
          S3(String u, String p, String Bucket)
           {super(new BasicAWSCredentials(u, p));
            bucket = Bucket;
           }
          boolean put(String k, String v)      
           {try 
             {final ByteArrayInputStream b = new ByteArrayInputStream(v.toString().getBytes());
              putObject(bucket, k, b, new ObjectMetadata());
              setObjectAcl(bucket, k, CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);  // Has to be here to allow change to reduced redundancy
              changeObjectStorageClass(bucket, k, StorageClass.ReducedRedundancy);
              setObjectAcl(bucket, k, CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);  // Has to be repeated because it is now a new object again
              return true; 
             }
            catch(Exception e) {log("Cannot put "+bucket+"/"+k+" to S3 because "+e);}
            return false; 
           }
          String get(String k) 
           {try 
             {final S3Object f = getObject(bucket, k);
              final BufferedInputStream i = new BufferedInputStream(f.getObjectContent());  
              final StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(); 
              final byte[]b = new byte[1024];
              for(int n = i.read(b); n != -1; n = i.read(b)) {s.append(new String(b, 0, n));}
              return s.toString(); 
             }
            catch(Exception e) {log("Cannot get "+bucket+"/"+k+" from S3 because "+e);}
            return null; 
           }
          String[]list(String d) 
           {try 
             {final ObjectListing l = listObjects(bucket, d);
              final List<S3ObjectSummary> L = l.getObjectSummaries(); 
              final int n = L.size();
              final String[]s = new String[n];  
              for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
               {final S3ObjectSummary k = L.get(i);
                s[i] = k.getKey();
               } 
              return s; 
             }
            catch(Exception e) {log("Cannot list "+bucket+"/"+d+" on S3 because "+e);}
            return new String[]{}; 
           }
         }
       }
```